# Dependency checker for Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am working on a relatively big Django project. We are splitting up the project into several (non-reuseable) apps. As part of our CI, I would like to have a way to enforce that no dependencies are introduced that would violate the architecture of the application. In particular, I want to ensure that dependencies between apps only go in one direction. For example:

```
workspace/
    project/
    main_app/
    addon_app1/
    addon_app2/
```

- `project` is allowed to import from everywhere.
- Nothing outside of `project` is allowed to import from `project`.
- `main_app` is not allowed to import from anywhere (except stdlib and third-party packages).
- `addon_app1` is allowed to import form `main_app`, but not from `addon_app2`.
- `addon_app2` is allowed to import from `main_app` and from `addon_app1`.

Is there an existing tool that can be used for this? I found `z3c.dependencychecker` and `snakefood`, but they are not Python 3 compatible. Ideally, I would like to have something that

- is Python 3 compatible
- does not require me to create setuptools boilerplate for my apps (since these apps are not intended to be distributed independently)
- can easily be used non-interactively.

But I am fine with doing some of the work myself, if I have to (e.g. port some code to Python 3), so please suggest solutions even if they do not meet all three requirements.

Comment: Django initialization and cyclic dependencies <3